# Increase mouse wheel step in QML ScrollView

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `GridView` in a `ScrollView`.

The default scrolling speed/stepping for the mouse wheel is just a few pixels and I would like to increase it. What is the better way for doing this?

I am using Qt5.3.

Comment: I also find it very frustrating. Given how nice the flick is, I wonder how hard it would be to connect up the scroll wheel to flick.

Comment: I am using my own custom scroll view based on the code of ScrollView. You can play with onVerticalValueChanged in the WheelArea (see ScrollView.qml). I have some nasty code replacing the line: flickableItem.contentY = verticalValue

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `__wheelAreaScrollSpeed` property of a ScrollView to set its scroll speed.

```
ScrollView {
    __wheelAreaScrollSpeed: 50
    Item {} //The content you wish to scroll
}
```